# Trying to plot same column from different dataframes on same axes, but only the first dataframe's data is plotted

Tags: r, shiny

I have n dataframes, each having the columns A, B, C. The first row is the column name and the second row is again the column name but in small letters (a, b, c). The data starts from the 3rd row onwards. I wish to plot the selected column (either A, B or C selected using radioButtons), for all the n dataframes on the same axes, in base R. The shifted_df object is the list of the n dataframes, the file_num_2 checkbox is the list of the  names of the dataframes for selection, the variable_to_plot radiobuttons is the name of the columns (A, B, C).
However, the plot is being made only for the first datframe out of the selected ones, i.e. if more than one dataframe is selected, then only the first one is plotted. I think the issue is related to the fact that df_to_plot is different for different "points" (in plotOutput, because up till that point the code seems to be working fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(checkmate)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App "),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Sample Data",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 9,
            fileInput("file_1", "Please choose Excel file", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
                 
          ),
        )
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        "Comparison Panel",
        uiOutput("Variables_2"),
        plotOutput(
          outputId = "live_plot_3",
          height = '250px',
          width = '250px',
          click = "plot_click_3",
          brush = brushOpts(id = "plot3_brush_3", resetOnNew = TRUE)
        )

        
      )
      
      
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  files_list_creator_1 <- reactive({
    files_list <- list()
    for (paths in input$file_1$datapath){ 
      file_to_add <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paths))
      #print(as.data.frame(read_excel(paths)))
      files_list <- append(files_list, list(file_to_add))
    
    }
    return(files_list) 
    
  })

  output$Variables_2 <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    
    if (length(files_list_creator_1()) == 0) {
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        ),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "variable_to_plot",
          label = "Available variables",
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        )
      )
    } else {
      choicenames = paste0(colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]]), sep = "  ", files_list_creator_1()[[1]][1,])
      choicevalues = colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]])
      for (i in 1:length(files_list_creator_1())){
        choicenames = append(choicenames,paste0(colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[i]]), sep = "  ", files_list_creator_1()[[i]][1,]))
        choicevalues = append(choicevalues, colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[i]]))
      }
      choicenames = unique(choicenames)
      choicevalues = unique(choicevalues)
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
          choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
          selected = as.character(1)
        ),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "variable_to_plot",
          label = "Available variables",
          choiceNames = choicenames,
          choiceValues = choicevalues,
          selected = (colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]]))[[1]]
        )
      )
    }
    tagList(taglist) 
  })

   shifted_df = reactiveValues()
   observeEvent(input$file_1,{
    for (i in 1:length(files_list_creator_1())){
      shifted_df[[paste0(i)]] = files_list_creator_1()[[i]]
    
    }
    
  })

  output$live_plot_3 = renderPlot({
    legend_labels = character(0)
    for (i in 1:length(input$file_num_2)){
      f = as.integer(input$file_num_2[[i]])
      if (input$variable_to_plot %in% colnames(shifted_df[[paste0(f)]])){
        df_to_plot = shifted_df[[paste0(f)]]
        x_names = colnames(df_to_plot)[[1]] #this line is hardcoded, need to change the default x variable
        y_names = input[["variable_to_plot"]]
        legend_labels = c(legend_labels, input$file_num_2[[i]])
        j = i

        break
      }
      
    }
    
    point_size = 0.5
    point_type = 19
    color_code = 1
    
    if(!is.null(df_to_plot)){
      p = plot(df_to_plot[,x_names], df_to_plot[,y_names], 
               xlab = paste0(x_names,sep ="  ",df_to_plot[1,x_names]), ylab = paste0(y_names,sep ="  ",df_to_plot[1,y_names[[1]]]), col = color_code, 
               pch= point_type, cex = point_size)
    }
    if (length(input$file_num_2) > 1 & j<length(input$file_num_2)){ 
      for (i in (j+1):length(input$file_num_2)){ 
        color_code = color_code + 1
        if (input$variable_to_plot %in% shifted_df[[paste0(input$file_num_2[[i]])]]){
          df_to_plot = shifted_df[[paste0(input$file_num_2[[i]])]]
          x_names = colnames(df_to_plot)[[1]]
          p = p+points(df_to_plot[,x_names], df_to_plot[,y_names], col = color_code, pch = point_type, cex = point_size)
          legend_labels = c(legend_labels, input$file_num_2[[paste0(input$file_num_2[[i]])]])        
        }
      }
      legend("topright", legend = legend_labels, col = 1:(length(input$file_num_2) + 1), pch = point_type)
    }

  })
  
  ranges_3 <- reactiveValues(x_3 = NULL, y_3 = NULL)

}

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Some of your `for` loops may not be working as intended, replace them with `lapply()`.

Comment: @YBS can you please explain how to apply lapply in this context, (especially in the plotOutput)?

Comment: Please make a *minimal* reproducible example.  In removing your irrelevant code, you may well find a solution to the problem yourself.

Comment: Does this work fine outside of shiny? If not, then please remove the shiny portion of the question, that'll help (considerably) reduce the size of the code in your question, and help to focus on the actual problem. (I find debugging plotting questions inside of a running `shiny` app usually unnecessary.)

Comment: Also, consider preprocessing your data frames so that the contain only the data you want plotted.  For example, if I understand you correctly, the fact that you have (different versions) of the column name in the first two rows of your data frames coreces all your columns to character.  Is that what you want?  You may also find it easier to bind all your input data into a single data frame (with an ID variable) and then subset/filter on the Id variable to select the points you want to plot.

Comment: @Limey the columns are not getting coerced to character. The plotting works fine if I do it only for a single dataframe at a time. However, I will try to make a shorter example and  see if that helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues. First, the condition `if (input$variable_to_plot %in% shifted_df[[paste0(input$file_num_2[[i]])]])` always fails resulting in not being able to add additional points.  Change it to `if (input$variable_to_plot %in% colnames(shifted_df[[paste0("_",f)]])){`.  Next, `input$file_num_2` is a vector, so you should use `input$file_num_2[i]` and not `input$file_num_2[[i]]`.  I would consider using `ggplot` instead of `plot`. However, your working code is below (perhaps you may need to further update it).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App "),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Sample Data",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 9,
            fileInput("file_1", "Please choose Excel file", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse")
          ),
        )
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        "Comparison Panel",
        uiOutput("Variables_2"),
        plotOutput(
          outputId = "live_plot_3",
          height = '250px',
          width = '250px',
          click = "plot_click_3",
          brush = brushOpts(id = "plot3_brush_3", resetOnNew = TRUE)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  files_list_creator_1 <- reactive({
    files_list <- list()
    for (paths in input$file_1$datapath){ 
      file_to_add <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paths))
      #print(as.data.frame(read_excel(paths)))
      files_list <- append(files_list, list(file_to_add))
      
    }
    return(files_list) 
    
  })
  
  output$Variables_2 <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    
    if (length(files_list_creator_1()) == 0) {
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        ),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "variable_to_plot",
          label = "Available variables",
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        )
      )
    } else {
      choicenames = paste0(colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]]), sep = "  ", files_list_creator_1()[[1]][1,])
      choicevalues = colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]])
      for (i in 1:numVar){
        choicenames = append(choicenames,paste0(colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[i]]), sep = "  ", files_list_creator_1()[[i]][1,]))
        choicevalues = append(choicevalues, colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[i]]))
      }
      choicenames = unique(choicenames)
      choicevalues = unique(choicevalues)
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
          choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
          selected = as.character(1)
        ),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "variable_to_plot",
          label = "Available variables",
          choiceNames = choicenames,
          choiceValues = choicevalues,
          selected = (colnames(files_list_creator_1()[[1]]))[[1]]
        )
      )
    }
    tagList(taglist) 
  })
  
  shifted_df = reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$file_1,{
    n <- length(files_list_creator_1())
    lapply(1:n, function(i){
      shifted_df[[paste0("_",i)]] <<- files_list_creator_1()[[i]]
    })
  })
  
  output$live_plot_3 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$file_num_2)
    legend_labels = character(0)
    m <- length(input$file_num_2)
    
    #lapply(1:m, function(i){
    for (i in 1:m){
      #print(i)
      f = as.integer(input$file_num_2[[i]])
      #print(f)
      if (input$variable_to_plot %in% colnames(shifted_df[[paste0("_",f)]])){
        #print(input$variable_to_plot)
        df_to_plot = shifted_df[[paste0("_",f)]]
        x_names = colnames(df_to_plot)[[1]] #this line is hardcoded, need to change the default x variable
        y_names = input[["variable_to_plot"]]
        #print(x_names)
        #print(y_names)
        legend_labels = c(legend_labels, input$file_num_2[i])
        j = i
        #print('j')
        # print(j)
        break
      }
      
    }
    # })
    point_size = 0.5
    point_type = 19
    color_code = 1
    
    if(!is.null(df_to_plot)){
      p = plot(df_to_plot[,x_names], df_to_plot[,y_names], 
               xlab = paste0(x_names,sep ="  ",df_to_plot[1,x_names]), ylab = paste0(y_names,sep ="  ",df_to_plot[1,y_names[[1]]]), col = color_code, 
               pch= point_type, cex = point_size)
      if (m > 1) { # & j<length(input$file_num_2)){ 
        n <- length(input$file_num_2)
        lapply(2:n, function(i) {
          # for (i in (j+1):length(input$file_num_2)){
          
          #print(paste0(input$file_num_2[[i]]))
          #print(color_code)
          color_code = color_code + 1
          #print("color code:")
          #print(color_code)
          if (input$variable_to_plot %in% names(shifted_df[[paste0("_",input$file_num_2[i])]])){
            df_to_plot = shifted_df[[paste0("_",input$file_num_2[i])]]
            x_names = colnames(df_to_plot)[1]
            p <<- p + points(df_to_plot[,x_names], df_to_plot[,y_names], col = color_code, pch = point_type, cex = point_size)
            legend_labels = c(legend_labels, input$file_num_2[paste0(input$file_num_2[i])])        
          }
        })
        legend("topright", legend = legend_labels, col = 1:(n + 1), pch = point_type)
      }
    }
    
    grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,
         lty = 2,      
         col = "gray", 
         lwd = 1) 
  })
  
  ranges_3 <- reactiveValues(x_3 = NULL, y_3 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$plot3_brush_3, {
    brush <- input$plot3_brush_3
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges_3$x_3 <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges_3$y_3 <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
      
    } else {
      ranges_3$x_3 <- NULL
      ranges_3$y_3 <- NULL
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$zoom_reset_3,{
    ranges_3$x_3 = NULL
    ranges_3$y_3 = NULL
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @YBS  adding the word "colnames" before "shifted_df" worked. I didn't have to change the indexing from [[]] to [] though.